# What would happen if Lost Mode is activated while an iPhone is in use?

Tags: iphone, find-my-iphone

Sadly my iPhone was stolen the other day while I was using it.

I activated Lost Mode as soon as I physically could. If the thief managed to keep the phone unlocked in the meanwhile, does the phone automatically lock when the Lost Mode is activated?

Just for clarity, I received an email from Apple stating that:

> “Lost Mode enabled on X’s iPhone
> This device was put into Lost Mode at 06:00 PST on 10 March 2022.
> Use the Find My app on an iPhone, iPad or Mac, or visit icloud.com/find to take additional action.